# Working with dates in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a simple PL SQL code. However it is failing at date level. The date column is CODT. I declared CODT as date. And in database level, it is date with format YYYY-MM-DD.

I also tried alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'; But it is throwing error.

The error message is ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

1830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Could you let me know where I need to change it to date format/ where I am making a mistake ?

```
    DECLARE

    RID      VARCHAR2(100);
    KY       VARCHAR2(200);
    CODT     DATE;

    CURSOR FETCH_DTLS IS

    SELECT ROW_ID, 
           KEY, 
           CUT_OFF_DT,
    FROM TMP1
    WHERE RN = 1;

    BEGIN

    OPEN FETCH_DTLS;

    LOOP

    FETCH FETCH_DTLS 
    INTO RID,
         KY,
         CODT;

    EXIT WHEN FETCH_DTLS%NOTFOUND;

    INSERT INTO tmp2
    VALUES
    (RID,
     KY,
     CODT
    );

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    CLOSE FETCH_DTLS;

    COMMIT;

    END;
```

Comment: What is the data type of `CUTT_OFF_DT` in table `tmp1`? Don't assume and don't guess; run `describe tmp1` and see what it tells you. Hint: you mentioned in database level it is "with format <whatever>." Columns in DATE datatype do not have a format. It is very likely that in the database level you have a string of some sort (perhaps VARCHAR2), not a date. And if so, you must convert it to a date first.

Comment: Yes, in TMP1 table, it is VARCHAR2(50 CHAR). But in TMP2 table, it is DATE.

Comment: Perfect. Then replace `CUT_OFF_DT` with `to_date(CUT_OFF_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` in the `SELECT`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have date column which **defined varchar2** in db you should use it like this:`to_date(your_column/*CUT_OFF_DT*/, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 0):

when you use **VARCHAR2** field and insert it in a table with **DATE** data-type, then you tell oracle to: Cast **VARCHAR2** to **DATE**

So your mistake is casting without providing any format, here are some date format examples used in oracle:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

there is also another function in oracle called **TO_DATE** which will do the job, it simply casts the string(char or varchar) to date with provided date-format and also provided calendar! Here is some examples:

```
TO_DATE('2016-12-15','YYYY-MM-DD')--uses default calendar of session
TO_DATE('2016-12-15','YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=gregorian')
TO_DATE('1395-09-25','YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=persian')--Solar base date used in IRAN
```

and reverse function is **TO_CHAR**

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')--SYSDATE is in Date type so this works
```

there is another data-type related to dates, which is called **TIMESTAMP**

```
TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF')--SYSTIMESTAMP is in TIMESTAMP type so this works
```

finally we can use **INTERVAL** type to calculate interval between 2 dates(Specially timestamps) and there is a useful function called numtodsinterval which converts numbers to intervals, you can use it like this:

```
SYSDATE+NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'Minute')
```

and this is an example:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'Minute'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM  DUAL
```

which outputs:

```
1   2016-12-15 15:05:10 2016-12-15 15:06:10
```

I hope it will be useful in your future usages of **DATE**, goodluck